# Measuring the entropy change in our body

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

What is an efficient way to measure the entropy change of our body in a day? Do we measure work done by the heart or such?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean entropy change ? Or entropy flow ? The amount of entropy in the body is rather constant. Whatever is created in the body comes out. The basic metabolism is very roughly 6000 kJ. This will go into heat, that will exit the body to the ambient air. Extra intake of energy might at least in part be used to do work, and will **not** become heat, and thus not create entropy within the body. Skin temperature is about 37°C i.e. 310°K.

So one can very roughly estimate the entropy flux as 20 kiloJoules per Kelvin. 
Since the air is slightly colder than the skin, the increase of entropy in the air is a bit larger.

Answer (score 2):

I have a totally different perspective on this.  The change in entropy of ones body from one day to the next depends only on the initial and final states of the body, and not on the details of the irreversible processes (including heat interchange  with the surroundings) that took the body from the initial to the final state.  This change is a function only of the initial and final cellular makeups of the body.  So it is determined by the increase in new cells and the death of old cells.  The heat exchange has nothing to do with this.  Of course, determination of the changes in the numbers of cells of various kinds would be a pretty daunting task, involving the biochemistry of the system.

If the body were experiencing only reversible changes, it might be possible to establish the entropy change by considering the entropy heat flux, and the changes in entropy between the waste products exiting and the fuel products entering (air and food).  However, the actual changes are not irreversible, so this approach can't be used.

Comment: Of course we are experiencing irreversible changes. But the amount of entropy associated is very small compared to heat created by metabolising food and evacuated to the outside. There are orders of magnitude between these amounts. Which does not mean that entropy does **not** continuously increase in the body. But quantitatively, this is peanuts compared to the basic heat flux and associated entropy flux.

Comment: That’s consistent with what I said.

Comment: The OP asks whether we can **measure** the change, by "measuring work", by thermodynamical ways. My answer is actual entropy **changes** are negligible compared to thermodynamical fluxes in and out. What you suggest would make sense If one could measure the entropy of each part of the body by a biological/biochemical means, but you admit that it is "a pretty daunting task".

Comment: Even if the entropy changes were not negligible compared to the entropy fluxes, your approach could not be used for this irreversible process because it would not account for entropy generation within the system.

Comment: Your first sentence would require  either that initial and final state would be equilibrium states. or that you provide a definition of change of entropy for non equilibrium states. What's your opinion?

Comment: I never claimed it was **possible** to compute the entropy changes by this way. On the contrary my whole point was to convince the OP that it was totally **impossible** to compute the entropy change through thermodynamical methods, contrary to his notion that one could "measure work done by the heart or such"

Comment: Then we are in total agreement.

Comment: @ChetMiller Indeed.

Comment: @GiorgioP Of course in the human body, it is in practice totally impossible to compute entropy changes. But in principle, and also in practice for much smaller and simpler systems, entropy and in particular changes of entropy can be defined for non equilibrium states. For instance, suppose two containers, one containing cold hydrogen, the other one warm oxygen, both so dilute the mean free path is **large** compared to the size of the boxes .Remove the partition between the boxes. Very rapidly you'll get a mixture of both gases in the full volume, with a first  entropy increase.

Comment: But it will take a much longer time for collisions to induce energy exchange between the molecules of the different gases. All this time the system is out of equilibrium, but you can still define the entropy if you know the velocity distribution function of each gas which is not beyond measurement.

Comment: @GiorgioP Some people subscribe to the notion that, even for non-equilibrium states of a system, we can determine the entropy by integrating the local entropy per unit mass over the mass of the system.  I happen to be one of those people.  Whether we admit it or not, in the case of chemically reacting systems evolving toward equilibrium, we implicitly do that when we calculate G as a function of conversion, and determine the conversion that minimizes G.

Comment: @ChetMiller  I agree on the possibility of defining the entropy of a system in local thermodynamic equilibrium (LTE), even though it is not *globally* at equilibrium. That is consistent with the additivity property of equilibrium entropy. However, not all non-equilibrium systems are in LTE or, better, the possibility that a system can be considered in LTE strongly depends on the  scale of time. Such scale of time should be  related to typical time scale of the dynamics as well as to entropy production rate. Could we estimate/measure both for a human body?

Comment: @GiorgioP I agree with what you are saying, but I don't know how to estimate/measure what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

A very interesting question.

When the body transfers heat to its surroundings it loses entropy. On the other hand, the oxidation processes for metabolizing food (glucose) generates entropy in the body. The change in entropy I suppose is the difference between the two. You may want to do some research on the internet. I found the following link interesting:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2634157

Whether overall our entropy increases or decreases each day, I can't quantify. But we know that entropy is associated with irreversible changes. And we know that aging is an irreversible process. So in that respect, I would think that the overall change in entropy of our bodies is increasing. But I confess, I have no equations to back up that opinion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would estimate that the increase of entropy within a body (unless the weight of the person varies a lot) over one's entire life is totally negligible compared to the day-by-day flux due to the basic metabolism, integrated over an entire life !

Comment: @Alfred That's interesting. Do  you have any numbers, or can you cite any research to back that up? Also, if the change is negligible, how do we account for the irreversible processes associated with aging? I thought those have been connected to oxidation processes- thus the idea that anti oxidants might slow the aging process down.

Comment: I did not say it was "negligible" in any absolute sense of the word. As far as ageing is concerned, we do age. What I am saying is that, barring the case of some thin person becoming obese (and even in that case, really) the amount of entropy stored in the body in a lifetime is very small compared to the **flux** of entropy just due to the basic metabolism, day after day, over a whole life. And no,   I don't have any numbers, it is just a hunch. What is the amount of food one consumes over one's entire life, compared to one's weight ?

Comment: @ Bob D I would agree that a person who, from his (or her) teens puts on 10 kgs per year and dies before the age 40 when weighing more than 300 kgs did store a non-negligible fraction of the entropy that was created in his/her body by metabolism of the food  consumed. But you'd agree this case is a bit extreme....

Comment: @Alfred ok perhaps entropy is not continuously increasing as a stored quantity as much as its generation causes irreversible changes in the body and perhaps it is those changes (disorder) that accumulate over time as opposed to the generation of entropy causing the changes. Then again, maybe I just don’t know what I’m talking about! I admitted it was speculative. But fun to debate

Comment: @Alfred  Hmm, or perhaps it is continuously increasing but extremely slowly as reflected in the slowly accumulating irreversible changes in our bodies associated with aging.

Comment: Certainly entropy would increase in older people. It is just that this increase is orders of magnitudes less than the enormous amount that is created by the day-by-day metabolism, 99,9... % is eliminated as heat in the environment, and a very small amount remains as an increase in disorder in the cells as we get older. But an extremely small amount, quantitatively, does mean a lot of problems that people my age start to feel qualitatively !

Comment: @Alfred Agree. Most of the generated entropy is passed to the environment as heat and mass transfer- the body being an open system. It is interesting that, according to one paper,